# How to improve the performance of StringBuilder while constructing log cause it expands capacity?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, thrift

I use thrift as a RPC framework in project which automatically generates toString method using StringBuilder. But when the object is too big, using flame graph I found StringBuilder cost a lot while expanding capacity too many times. Is there any ways I could optimize it?

Comment: You can try to use a constructor `StringBuilder(initialCapacity)` to avoid reallocation.

Comment: try to give more information

Comment: First, I could not accurately estimate the capacity. Secondly, the toString method is generated automatically which could not overwrite.

Comment: Could you share your insights at the Thrift dev mailing list please? Thanks!